# pygame sound format differences

Tags: python, pygame, audio

For playing my sounds I have this working code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([100,100])
print(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels(),"cannels")
sounda = pygame.mixer.Sound("track.mp3")
print("Length",sounda.get_length())
print("Volume",sounda.get_volume())
channela = sounda.play()
while channela.get_busy():
   pygame.time.delay(100)
pygame.quit()
```

You can see I am mostly using .mp3 files.

But my problem is that it can play some sounds but others result the error which says that the sound can not be loaded. Are there any differences between mp3 files and do you know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: With mixer.music I can play the sounds without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found out there can be differences in one sound format so that pygame has problems with it. With the program ocenaudio I can manipulate and save my sounds in multiple types of the .wav format. Pygame can deal with one of them.

But loading music has never been a problem...

Answer (score 0):

If Pygame is not loading your audio, there are 3 possibilities.

## Possibility 1:

Pygame cannot find your file.  When saying the name of a file, make sure either the sound file is in the same directory as your program file, or you can give the entire file path instead (like '/home/person/sound.mp3', instead of just 'sound.mp3'.)

## Possibility 2:

Your file is the wrong format.  Though it is called .mp3, it may be a different type.  Try using an audio conversion program.

## Possibility 3:

Pygame just plain cannot read the file.  Pygame works best with .ogg files, but sometimes has issues with other types.  Just use an audio conversion program to convert it to .ogg, and it might work.

If none of these work, giving an exact error message would be appreciated.